# Angular 2 parent's path replaced with child's path

Tags: angular, nested-routes

This is my current routes config of latest version Angular app

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'board', component: BoardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'stories', component: StoryComponent }]},
    { path: '**',   redirectTo: 'board', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

It works fine, both components are displayed, I want to work it the same way but with a little change: when user routes to `/board/stories`, I want the path to be just `/stories`, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Hi Louen, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm having a hard time discerning exactly what you are trying to do here, can you perhaps provide some images/diagrams, or some code with comments explaining what you'd like to happen on each line?

Comment: @Louen Leoncoeur its difficult to understand your use case could you provide a template of code or some relevance?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I've made some changes and hope It's more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the way your routes are defined - No, it is not possible.**

By defining `stories` as a child of `board` you quite literally defined your route to be `.../board/stories`. Therefore a route of just `/stories` will not match any route as you have it defined.

If you want the route to just be `/stories` then you could simply redefine your routes to be

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'board', component: BoardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'stories', component: StoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '**',   redirectTo: 'board', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: Okay, but then either a BoardComponent or StoryComponent is displayed. I want BoardComponent to be displayed for `/board` path and both BoardComponent and StoryComponent to be displayed for `/stories` path and additionally BoardComponent should save its state (scroll position and etc) when routes change from `/board` to `/stories` and vice versa

Comment: Yes, well **what you want to happen unfortunately does not influence what will happen** based on the design constraints of the Angular framework. If you want the `board` component & `stories` component to be displayed at the same time then you can keep `stories` component a child (as you have) or consider using a secondary `router-outlet`.